# Not able to print in Spark streaming application

Tags: spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

The spark streaming application is not printing simple statements to the `driver's stdout` , Here I am trying to print some statement , just after transforming the dstream_2, but it is only getting printed ofr the first batch only. I expected it to be printed for every batch execution.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-cluster")
                               .setAppName("SparkJob")
                               .set("spark.executor.memory","2G")
                               .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout","5")


val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Minutes(1))

var historyRdd: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD

var historyRdd_2: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD


val stream_1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_1))
val dstream_2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_2))


val dstream_2 = stream_2.map((r: Tuple2[String, GenericData.Record]) => 
{
  //some mapping
}
//Not Working
print("Printing Test")
val historyDStream = dstream_1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd))
dstream_2.foreachRDD(r => r.repartition(500))
val historyDStream_2 = dstream_2.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd_2))
val fullJoinResult = historyDStream.fullOuterJoin(historyDStream_2)

 val filtered = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._1.isEmpty)


filtered.foreachRDD{rdd =>

  val formatted = rdd.map(r  => (r._1 , r._2._2.get)) 

  historyRdd_2.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
  historyRdd_2 = formatted // assign the new history
  historyRdd_2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}


val filteredStream = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._2.isEmpty)


filteredStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  val formatted = rdd.map(r => (r._1 , r._2._1.get)) 
  historyRdd.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
  historyRdd = formatted // assign the new history
  historyRdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print("Printing Test")` on that position will only get printed once when the program is first evaluated. 
To add some console output on each batch interval, we need to place the I/O operation in the scope of an output operation:

This will get printed every time:

```
dstream2.foreachRDD{ _ -> print("Printing Test") }
```

Comment: Is this same for the logging(slf4j)?

Comment: can you also provide the reason for this printing behaviour.

Comment: Should be the same for log statements.  Re behavior: spark streaming operates on dstreams. Anything outside the scope of a dstream operation will be evaluated as any normal code in a program. Thr impottant thing to understand is that the operations on dstreams are only declared in the program. The actual execution happens in the spark streaming scheduler.

Comment: So if I have to do some computation in the script and then dump it to HDFS  , how can I be able to do that. And also invoking `foreachRDD` might give a overhead.

Comment: I suggest you try and ask a new question if needed